# What happens to pound cakes if I forget the flour and then add it after baking a little?

Tags: baking, cake

I was making pound cakes. I put the mixture in loaf pans, noticing the consistency looked off. I put them in the oven and about 5 minutes later I realized I forgot to put in the flour. I took the pans out, added everything to the flour and put them back in the oven. They are cooking at 300° for 1 hour 25 min. Will they turn out or not?

Comment: Tough to say, but when you find out, you should answer your own question!

Comment: To answer the question in the title (i.e. what happens if you just bake a mixture of butter, sugar, eggs, and flavorings), you may get something custard-like, but then again, you might just get a curdled mess.

Comment: Be interested to find out what happened, but I suspect if you blended everything together that 5 minutes wasn't enough to set anything up except a skin

Comment: Hi peggym7. How'd your cakes turn out? As you can see, a number of people are curious. Posting an answer would be a great way to teach the rest of us! Hope all went well and they were yummy!

Comment: Wow this question was posted in 2015..I think the cake was too bad she had to quit stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You will end up with a very sweet sunken souffle type item without the flour.

Comment: But she did eventually add the flour... This question seems to be asking "will my cake still work out if I add the flour after I started baking it?"